# How to load int and char use BufferedReader in java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a question about how to load `int` and `char` using `BufferedReader` in java.

I need to load in a given `String str ="2 3 XX...XXXX..."`... something like that. It contains 2 integers and a `String`.

Now I need to load the 2 numbers first and then I need to load the string  and I then need to read the string char by char, like read the `XX...XXXX...` part as `X` and `X` and `.` and so on. Here is part of my code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String str=br.readLine();
   number1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
   number2 = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

But this seems to be wrong and I don't know how to continue. So can anyone tell me how to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the input will be exactly the same every time, you could split by spaces like so:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str = br.readLine();
String[] stringArray = str.split("\\s+");
```

This will give you an array of strings. You can then extract the ints and chars by taking the indexs of the `stringArray`:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]);
char[] charArray = stringArray[2].toCharArray();
```

To access the first char, you would write:

```
char char1 = charArray[0];
```

Comment: If a number does not come when you expect, you may have to handle NumberFormatException.

Comment: Yeah, there's plenty of things you should do if you couldn't be sure of the input, but this is assuming (based on the question) that the input will be the same format every time

Answer (score 0):

This quick and dirty program parses them all. Just copy-paste and run it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "12 345 abcdef";
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));
    int state = 1;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = reader.read(); i != -1; i = reader.read()) {
        char c = (char) i;
        switch (state) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            if (c == ' ') {
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(builder.toString()));
                builder = new StringBuilder();
                state++;
            } else {
                builder.append(c);
            }
            break;
        default:
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
12
345
abcdef
```